# connecting Canopy to mysql

Tags: mysql, enthought, canopy

I am new to Python and using Enthought Canopy Express for learning purpose. As part of that I am looking for an option to connect Canopy to mysql. I did not find any materials. Please share if you know any method that I can use mysql in Canopy Express.

I am using Mac OS X version 10.9

Path for canopy is: 
/Users/mz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Mysql is version 5.6 with the following path: 
mysql is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Canopy Package Manager to install `pymysql`:
[image]

Once installed, access `pymysql` according to the Python [PEP249 DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) (create a connection, get a cursor, etc.):

```
In [1]: import pymysql

In [2]: connection = pymysql.connect?
Signature: pymysql.connect(*args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
        Establish a connection to the MySQL database. Accepts several
        arguments:

        host: Host where the database server is located
        user: Username to log in as
        password: Password to use.
        database: Database to use, None to not use a particular one.
        port: MySQL port to use, default is usually OK.
...
```

Comment: Hi Tim, after I connected to mysql using the command:  import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect (host='localhost', database='ali', user='root', password=''), how I can test that I am connected to the mysql

Comment: The next step would be to create a cursor and then use it to execute an SQL statement:  `cursor=connection.cursor(); cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table"); cursor.fetchall()`